# How do I boot Ubuntu which shares a harddive with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, bootloader

I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 each on its own partition. When I switch on the computer, I do not get the option of switching to Ubuntu. Windows 7 starts automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restore the GRUB bootloader. The Ubuntu Community site has a comprehensive set of instructions on this: [**Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some slightly more verbose instructions on how to repair grub. 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1035999

Answer (score 1):

Grub http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/ is a dual boot loader that you can install on the system, this will then give you the option to dual boot each OS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your GRUB bootloader is no longer set as the default bootloader... follow the steps below.

Boot with a live cd that has grub. Issue this:
su 
grub (enter)
root (hd0,?) (? being where your original grub is)
setup (hd0)
quite

Done!